# Problems with connecting Java DatagramSocket through WiFi

Tags: java, android, udp

The aim of the following code is to send a datagram packet via WiFi from a Android App to a TI CC3200 Launchpad. 
I'm currently experiencing a problem while establishing the connection to the Launchpad. I tried to test the procedure with a laptop and the app, but my Wireshark isn't displaying any packets. 
Any suggestions why my code isn't working as intended?

BR

**EDIT1:**

The IP's are correct.
I'm receiving: bind failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument).

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct"/>
```

**EDIT2:**

Stacktrace:

.
.
.

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

D/CustomFrequencyManagerService(  751): releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 2457600  uid : 1000  pid : 751  tag : ROTATION_BOOSTER@32

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1036): refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020495/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mobileLabel=bob wifiLabel="Kugelfahrzeug"xxxxXXXXxxxxXXXX emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel="Kugelfahrzeug"xxxxXXXXxxxxXXXX mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020113/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0202ac/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_3g mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f020114/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3g mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020495/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f02012b/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_wifi_4 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f020468/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_no_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080907/android:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1036): refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1036): applyOpen

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1036): refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1036): applyOpen

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1036): refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1036): applyOpen

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1036): refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1036): applyOpen

D/TaskPersister(  751): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=24_task.xml

D/TaskPersister(  751): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=24_task_thumbnail.png

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/art     (  751): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17486(1092KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(1360KB) LOS objects, 25% free, 45MB/61MB, paused 1.720ms total 181.936ms

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/WifiStateMachine(  751): CMD_RSSI_POLL : calculateWifiScore in!

I/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0

V/AudioPolicyManager(  287): ### curdevice : 2

I/WifiStateMachine(  751): CMD_RSSI_POLL : calculateWifiScore out!

I/WifiStateMachine(  751): CMD_RSSI_POLL : out!

**EDIT3:**

Problem was located at the network call in main (fixed with

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() 
 { 
    @Override 
    public void run() 
    {   
      (Code below)
    }
 });
```

)

App works now fine!

**Code:**

```
    public void runJavaSocket() throws IOException 
    {   
    try 
    {
        DSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        DSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.173.2", 4242));
        DSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.173.1", 4242));
        String send_x = Float.toString(round_x);
        byte[] buffer = send_x.getBytes(); 
        byte [] IP = {(byte) 192,(byte) 168,(byte) 173, (byte) 1};
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(IP);
        int serverSocket = 4242;
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, serverSocket);
        DSocket.send(packet);
        DSocket.close();     
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        DSocket.close();
    }
```

}

Comment: you aren't catching any exception? you are just eating it up. I assume DSocket is a class variable? when you connect with a DatagramSocket, you don't need do put the address and port in the packet - it will do it automatically. Print out your exception that you aren't checking and tell us what it says. Also, are you sure those are the IP Addresses of your computer? where is the listening end code? **Did you add INTERNET permission in android manifest?**

Comment: I updatet the question with more data about the problem.

Comment: I believe this is the problem. surprised I missed it first time around. `new DatagramSocket(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.173.2", 4242));` when you call bind with no arguments, it automatically binds to the default port. I believe you can also call `new DatagramSocket(null);` to tell it not to bind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Its now working when i try to send data from my laptop to the launchpad, but if i try the same with the app instead of the pc the app crashes. Is that because round_x is getting its data simultaneously from the gyro-sensor?

Comment: put the stacktrace from the android log

Comment: I've updatet the question, I also found out that the app only crashes through the lines .connect and .send.

Comment: Probably you make network call on main thread!?

Comment: Place your code on new thread: new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                }).start();

Comment: The App is working now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see how the new code you've posted can work. `new DatagramSocket()` already binds the socket, as pointed out by @WalterM, so the following `bind()` should fail. I also don't see how adding a thread changes anything. NB You don't need to *both* connect the socket *and* provide the target address in the `DatagramPacket`. Either will do.

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and post youw solution as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, and be sure that your two devices work on the same network:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DatagramSocket socket = null;
                try {
                    socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.8");
                    byte[] command = "Hello".getBytes("UTF-8");

                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(command, command.length, address, 8080);
                    socket.send(sendPacket);
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        socket.disconnect();
                        socket.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Try it why exactly? NB broadcast=false is the default state, and if the socket isn't connected it is futile to disconnect it. And `SocketException` should never be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the App starts crashing while using your code.

Comment: Irrelevant. Your snippet isn't equivalent to the OP's, as it doesn't bind the socket to port 4242. NB Calling `setReuseAddress(true)` seven lines after the socket is bound is completely pointless.